# What is the difference between drupal_get_form and drupal_retrieve_form?

Tags: 7, forms

What is the difference between [`drupal_get_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) and [`drupal_retrieve_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_retrieve_form/7)? Can someone explain the difference?  I look at the API, but the description seems similar to me.

Comment: I think one key difference is that `drupal_retrieve_form()` allows your code to access the updated `$form_state` as it's passed by reference, however `drupal_get_form()` just return the `$form`, not the state.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that `drupal_get_form()` handles retrieving, processing, and displaying a rendered HTML form for modules automatically, while `drupal_retrieve_form()` returns the structured array that defines a form.

#### Retrieving the form

`drupal_get_form()` first checks if the form is present in the form cache with [form_get_cache()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_get_cache/7); if it isn't present, it calls [drupal_retrieve_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_retrieve_form/7), and [drupal_prepare_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/7).

#### Processing the form

`drupal_get_form()` calls [drupal_process_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_process_form/7), which is the function that calls [drupal_validate_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_validate_form/7), and that invokes the submission handlers with [form_execute_handlers()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_execute_handlers/7).

#### Rendering the form

The rendering is done from `drupal_process_form()`, which calls [form_builder()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_builder/7).

In most of the cases, `drupal_get_form()` is the function to use, such as in the following code.

```
function node_menu() {
  $items['admin/content'] = array(
    'title' => 'Content', 
    'description' => 'Find and manage content.', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('node_admin_content'), 
    'access arguments' => array('access content overview'), 
    'weight' => -10, 
    'file' => 'node.admin.inc',
  );

  // …

  return $items;
}
```

The only module I found that is calling `drupal_retrieve_form()` directly is the Mollom module in [mollom_moderate()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/mollom_moderate/7), which uses it for automatically submitting a form. The code could use [drupal_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7), but (as a comment says), "Programmatic form submissions are not able to automatically use the primary form submit button/action, so we need to resemble `drupal_form_submit()`."

```
  $form_id = $form_info['delete form'];
  $form_state = form_state_defaults();
  // We assume that all delete confirmation forms take the fully loaded
  // entity as (only) argument.
  $messages[] = "Attempt to load $form_info[entity] entity via entity_load().";
  $entities = entity_load($data->entity, array($data->id));
  $form_state['build_info']['args'][] = $entities[$data->id];
  $form = drupal_retrieve_form($form_id, $form_state);

  $form_state['values'] = array();
  $form_state['values']['mollom']['feedback'] = '';
  // Take over the primary submit button of confirm_form().
  $form_state['values']['op'] = $form['actions']['submit']['#value'];

  $form_state['input'] = $form_state['values'];
  $form_state['programmed'] = TRUE;
  // Programmed forms are always submitted.
  $form_state['submitted'] = TRUE;

  // Reset form validation.
  $form_state['must_validate'] = TRUE;
  form_clear_error();

  drupal_prepare_form($form_id, $form, $form_state);
  drupal_process_form($form_id, $form, $form_state);

  $result = $form_state['executed'];
```