# Ajax form in preprocess_node never triggers

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

In a `preprocess_node` hook, I try to insert a Drupal node_form form in my page. I do it with this function:

```
function my_module_get_edit_form($selection) {
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.form');
  $form = drupal_get_form('selection_node_form', $selection);

  //here some code to disable (#access = FALSE) unwanted fields and options

  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Update',
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'smll_selection_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'selection_form'
    ),
  );

  return drupal_render($form);
}
```

The form is rendered properly but when I click my submit button, it always submits the form and forwards me to the node's page, no ajax call.

I tried adding #ajax array onto a select field in the same form (`$form['field_application_type']['und']['#ajax']`) but nothing is triggered when I change the select's value. No HTTP request, no Javascript error, nothing.

I tried using `drupal_build_form` with a manufactured `$form_state`.

I tried creating my form in an another function and calling it with `drupal_build_form`.

I tried setting `#ajax_processed` to `TRUE`.

The HTML id `selection_form` exists but, anyway, I never come to the moment the callback function is called.

Comment: What's in your smll_selection_ajax_callback?

Comment: `return "Yipee";`
But it is never called.

Comment: it seems it's not taking your actions at all, try to add a class attribute to see if it works. dsm the form before and after your changes and see if it actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the correct function for that;

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'selection_node_form' //and same condition you call your function){
    //do your changes here
  }
}
```

Or use `drupal_retrieve_form` then you can override the form.

The drupal_get_form call the function drupal_build_form which build the form, you can't override it that way.

Comment: I didn't manage to use properly `drupal_retrieve_form` but using `hook_form_alter` actually works, thank you Namari!

Comment: Check here to have more explanation: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51583/what-is-the-difference-between-drupal-get-form-and-drupal-retrieve-form